# how to store bitmaps into arrary in flex (action script3)?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, air, flash

In my project i used image array with 16+16 32+32 48+48 128+128 different size of image for system tray icon but i put on bitmes then shows

Error #2005: Parameter 0 is of the incorrect type. Should be type BitmapDat.

public  var imageURLs:Array =  ['icon/toy.png','toy32.png','TOY48.png','joy128.png'];
NativeApplication.nativeApplication.icon.bitmaps = new Array(imageURLs);

What did i wrong code . how do store image to bitmaps array ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should instead use the [`BitmapData`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/display/BitmapData.html) class. Read more about `Bitmap` and `BitmapData` classes [here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/Working_with_Bitmaps_03.html).

[Here's](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=taskbar_1.html) a tutorial on Flex taskbar icons.

Comment: NativeApplication.nativeApplication.icon.bitmaps = new Array(bitmapData());

public function  bitmapData():BitmapData{ 
var myBitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(40, 40, false, 0x0000FF00);
var clockImage:BitmapData = new BitmapData(this.width, this.height,true,0x0011111);
clockImage.draw(this);
return clockImage;
}  
i tried this code but it shows black image icon . i want my array stored icon . what i do ?

Comment: You need to first load the image and then copy it to a BitmapData. Please go through the second link.

Comment: images.push(event.target.content.bitmapData) what is mean ? do u know about that dirkgently

Comment: Added a link to a tutorial in my answer. The statement you have means 'images' is an array of BitmapData, and the 'push' method adds a bitmapData object to this array.